# Как скопировать от определенного символа несколько строк из Memo?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

```
function GetTextInPercent(aLine: string): string; 
var 
  i1, i2: Integer;
begin
  i1 := Pos('%', aLine) + 1;
  i2 := PosEx('%', aLine, i1);
  Result := Copy(aLine, i1, i2 - i1);
end;
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  k: integer;
begin                                                               
  for k:=0 to memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
  begin
   Que1.Lines.Text := Que1.Lines.Text + GetTextInPercent(Memo1.Lines.Strings[k]);
  end;
end;
```

Есть процедура, которая позволяет искать в тексте Memo символ '%' и выводить после него все, что находится после него до тех пор, пока не найдется такой же символ '%'. Но это работает только если символы на одной строке.
Как сделать, чтобы выводил по несколько строк?
Пример текста в Memo (Memo1):

> % Весной снег быстро растаял, вода поднялась и затопила бобровую хатку.Бобры перетащили бобрят на сухие листья, но вода подобралась ещё выше, и пришлось бобрятам расплываться в разные стороны. (Снегирёв Г.) %

Пример результата в другом Memo (Que1):

> Весной снег быстро растаял, вода поднялась и затопила бобровую хатку.Бобры перетащили бобрят на сухие листья, но вода подобралась ещё выше, и пришлось бобрятам расплываться в разные стороны. (Снегирёв Г.)

Answer (score 1):

При таком раскладе, вам надо как-то обрабатывать весь текст:

В целом принцип такой, что берем весь текст, находим первый % при помощи `PosEx('%', aText, 1)`, так же находим второй %, берем текст между ними при помощи `Copy`. А далее повторяем это в цикле, находим 3 и 4 %, потом 5 и 6 и каждый раз между ними берем текст.

Или же как-то поделить входной текст на части, чтобы в каждой было только по два знака % и передавать его в вашу функцию не по-строчно, а сразу весь (например `Memo1.Text`) (тогда переносы строк сохранятся)